# Vue 3 v-network-graph doesn't visualize edges correctly with data from an async function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, ref

I'm using the v-network-graph component to visualize a graph from data that I get from a server. The ref() doesn't work correctly. Here is the code I have:

```js
const nodes = ref()
const edges = ref ()
const layouts = ref()

const getMap = async () => {
  const data = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/get-map", {
      method: 'GET'})
      .then(response => response.json())
      
    console.log(data);
    
    if (data.nodes == null && data.edges == null && data.layouts == null) {
      props.logItems.push("please press explore button first")
    } else {
      //this is how I need my code to work
      layouts.value = JSON.parse(data.layouts) 
      nodes.value = JSON.parse(data.nodes)
      edges.value = JSON.parse(data.edges) 
      console.log(data.layouts)
      return{layouts}

      props.logItems.push("map generated")
    }
    
   
}
```

If I assign the layouts manually in the ref, it works correctly.

```js
 const layouts = ref({
 "nodes": {
    "n0": { "x": 0, "y": 0 },"n3": { "x": 0, "y": 200 },"n1": { "x": 200, "y": 0 },"n4": { "x": 200, "y": 200 },"n6": { "x": 0, "y": 400 },"n2": { "x": 400, "y": 0 },"n5": { "x": 400, "y": 200 },"n7": { "x": 200, "y": 400 }}
})
```

If I do the same thing in the getMap, it stops working.

```js
layouts.value = {
  "nodes": {
    "n0": { "x": 0, "y": 0 },"n3": { "x": 0, "y": 200 },"n1": { "x": 200, "y": 0 },"n4": { "x": 200, "y": 200 },"n6": { "x": 0, "y": 400 },"n2": { "x": 400, "y": 0 },"n5": { "x": 400, "y": 200 },"n7": { "x": 200, "y": 400 }}
 }
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Is `data.layouts/nodes/edges` actually of type `string`? Does the browser console show error messages for this code? If so, what's the message?

Comment: Yes, they are strings, the browser console doesn't show any errors.

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?